# Karma - Jasmine spy not being called when dispatching click event

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to write a test that checks if a function is called during a click event. However, the test is really inconsistent when running it via Karma. When I manually include all the scripts and markup, the test always runs successfully, but when using Karma, it is successful sometimes, and other times it results in the following error: `Expected spy downloadLineChart to have been called.`

I've tried various different Karma configurations, but the inconsistencies persist.

Below is a minimal reproduction of my included js files. I haven't included the karma.conf.js file, since the behavior is the same regardless of the config. I can include it if needed.

```js
// initialize-testbed.js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML +=
  `<canvas id="lineChartDisplay"></canvas>
  <a id="lineChartDownload"></a>`;
```

```js
// dashboard.js
const dashboard = {
  downloadLineChart() {
    const download = document.getElementById("lineChartDownload");
    const image = document.getElementById("lineChartDisplay").toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
    download.href = image;
    download.download = "LineChart.png";
  }
};

document.getElementById('lineChartDownload').addEventListener('click', () => { 
  dashboard.downloadLineChart();
});
```

And here's the failing test:

```js
// dashboard.spec.js
describe('dashboard', () => {
  it('should call the download function for each button click', () => {
    const lineChartDownload = document.getElementById('lineChartDownload');
    spyOn(dashboard, 'downloadLineChart');

    lineChartDownload.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));

    expect(dashboard.downloadLineChart).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I'm not sure if my implementation is wrong, or if I'm misunderstanding some concept. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not the solution but just a way to write clean code.. This `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML +
  '<canvas id="lineChartDisplay"></canvas>' +
  '<a id="lineChartDownload"></a>';` can be written as `document.body.innerHTML +=
  '<canvas id="lineChartDisplay"></canvas>' +
  '<a id="lineChartDownload"></a>';`

Comment: You're right. I just typed that up quickly as a simple short example.